# PHP switch with GET request

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

I am building a simple admin area for my site and I want the URLs to look somewhat like this:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/?home
http://mysite.com/admin/?settings
http://mysite.com/admin/?users
```

But I am not sure how I would retrieve what page is being requested and then show the required page. I tried this in my switch:

```
switch($_GET[])
{
    case 'home':
        echo 'admin home';
        break;
}
```

But I get this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\path\to\web\directory\admin\index.php on line 40`

Is there any way around this? I want to avoid setting a value to the GET request, like:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/?action=home
```

If you know what I mean. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` – that contains the bits after the `?`:

```
switch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    case 'home':
        echo 'admin home';
        break;
}
```

You can take this method even further and have URLs like this:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/?users/user/16/
```

Just use `explode()` to split the query string into segments, get the first one and pass the rest as arguments for the method:

```
$args = explode('/', rtrim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], '/'));
$method = array_shift($args);

switch($method) {
    case 'users':
        $user_id = $args[2];

        doSomething($user_id);
        break;
}
```

This method is popular in many frameworks that employ the MVC pattern. An additional step to get rid of the `?` altogether is to use `mod_rewrite` on Apache servers, but I think that's a bit out of scope for this question.

Comment: what if there are more vars other than page vars?

Comment: You don't even need mod_rewrite; `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` will contain everything after the script in the URL.

Comment: @Ignacio, that's true but then you need the `index.php` part there.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, and I'll probably be using this "MVC pattern" you talked about. :)

Answer (score 3):

As well as the ones mentioned, another option would be `key($_GET)`, which would return the first key of the $_GET array which would mean it would work with URLs with other parameters

> www.example.com/?home&myvar = 1;

The one issue is that you may want to use [reset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) on the array first if you have modified the array pointer as `key` returns the key of the element array pointer is currently pointing to.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP code:

```
switch($_GET){
    case !empty($_GET['home']):
       // code here
    break;

    case !empty($_GET['settings']):
         // code here
    break;   

    default:
         // code here
    break;
}
```

Comment: How does your answer improves previous accepted and upvoted answer? Code only answers are ok, but adding comments to your code increases its usefulness for future readers.

Comment: case true:

case false:

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 1):

Is not the most "elegant" way to do it but the simplest form to answer your question is..

```
    if (isset($_GET['home'])):  
        # show index..  
    elseif (isset($_GET['settings'])):  
        # settings...  
    elseif (isset($_GET['users'])):  
        # user actions..  
    else:  
        # default action or not...  
    endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your links "look nicer" by using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable.

This would allow you to use URLs like:

```
http://mysite.com/admin/home
http://mysite.com/admin/settings
http://mysite.com/admin/users
```

The PHP code used:

```
// get the script name (index.php)
$doc_self = trim(end(explode('/', __FILE__)));

/*
 * explode the uri segments from the url i.e.: 
 * http://mysite.com/admin/home 
 * yields:
 * $uri_segs[0] = admin
 * $uri_segs[1] = home
 */ 

// this also lower cases the segments just incase the user puts /ADMIN/Users or something crazy
$uri_segs = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]))));
if($uri_segs[0] === (String)$doc_self)
{
    // remove script from uri (index.php)
    unset($uri_segs[0]);
}
$uri_segs = array_values($uri_segs);

// $uri_segs[1] would give the segment after /admin/
switch ($uri_segs[1]) {
    case 'settings':
        $page_name = 'settings';
        break;
    case 'users':
        $page_name = 'users';
        break;
    // use 'home' if selected or if an unexpected value is given
    case 'home':
    default: 
        $page_name = 'home';
        break;
}
```