# Is this sanitization ok/enough for a page redirection using $_GET?

Tags: php, get, security, sanitization

I'm using $_get for a simple page redirection.
I've only just started learning about sanitizing user input, so I was wondering if the below code was ok. Is there any other sanitization that is recommended for this particular code? If yes, why?

About the code below. I checked that the user entered a value and then matched the value against a list of acceptable values before redirecting.

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$PAGES = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z');

if (empty($_GET['letter'])) { 
$_GET['letter']="a";
}

if (!in_array($_GET['letter'], $PAGES)) { 
$_GET['letter']="a";  
}

$letter=$_GET['letter']; 
$goto=$letter .".php";
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$goto");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As log as you keep $_GET['letter'] in a set of $PAGES i think you 'll be fine. However, your code is really bad!

May be this will help you:
[PHP switch with GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254321/php-switch-with-get-request)

Maybe you would be interested to use Zend Framework MVC.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html

You will find examples with mod_rewrite also. Happy reading !!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate on bad?

Comment: Sure. No code formating, $PAGES should not be capital, $letter variable is useless, maybe $goto also, you could use single quotes in "a" and ".php" and the second if should be in an else of the first.

Comment: Code formatting isn't a sign of bad code, though it could be tidied.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll try to work on improving my coding.

Comment: @Rich, sure but a had to make a comment about formating / readability

Answer (score 0):

Apache, mod_rewrite would be much better for this.

Comment: @Dagoon Thanks. Can you give me an example of how I would implement this with Apache?Also, why would Apache be better?

Comment: @Dagoon I don't think mod_rewrite alone would help.